# Insert into database in vb not working

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have the below snippet of code whenever I try registering the username exist part seems to be executed even for a username that doesn't exist in the database. Don't know where am wrong here any help will be appreciated.

```vb
'Connecting to SQL Database and executing Query------------------------------------------
Dim Strconn As String = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Database=QuizDB; Integrated Security = true"
Dim Strcmd As String = "INSERT INTO reg_info(uname,pass,fname,lname,dob,course,college) VALUES ('" & user_name.Text & "','" & con_pass.Text & "', '" & first_name.Text & "', '" & last_name.Text & "', '" & dob.Text & "', '" & course.Text & "', '" & college.Text & "');"
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim sqlcmd As SqlCommand
sqlconn = New SqlConnection(Strconn)
Try
    sqlconn.Open()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Could not connect to DataBase. Application will close now!", vbCritical, "Database Error")
    End
End Try
sqlcmd = New SqlCommand(Strcmd, sqlconn)
da.SelectCommand = sqlcmd
sqlcmd.Dispose()
sqlconn.Close()

'Exception Handling-----------------------

Dim exc As Exception = Nothing
Try
    da.Fill(ds)
Catch ex As Exception
    exc = ex
Finally
    If Not (exc) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox("User Name Already Exist. Please select a different User Name!", vbExclamation, "Already Exist")
        user_name.Focus()
    Else
        MsgBox("Registration Successful.", vbInformation, "Successful")
        Me.Close()
        Login.Show()
    End If
End Try
```

Comment: Why are you using *an `Exception` object* for your conditional?  Why are you *ignoring the exception*?  When you debug this, how *specifically* is it failing?  If `exc` has a value, what is that value?  What is the exception?  (Hint: Ignoring errors isn't a particularly effective way of resolving those errors.)

Comment: That is the wrong way to build SQL.  Use SQL parameters instead of concatenating strings.  Instead of those awful Catch messages print the real exception message and you would at least know what the error is. Exceptions  are not meant for code flow control.  And passwords should never be stored as plaintext, hash them

Comment: Thanks alot guys Am actually new to vb, and am using he exception object cause I thought its the right way of doing it. Am aware of the sql injection too. I just need specific guide on how to go about it. Thank you

Comment: Google is your friend.  Hundreds, nay thousands!, of answers here showing how to do it.  SQL params do more than prevent SQL injection attacks - they prevent datatype conversions, make the code more readable and prevent stupid errors with too many/too few ticks in the query string.

Comment: To be frank, I think hard-coding your "username already exists" message like that is pretty bad practice.  You're assuming that that's the only thing that would cause the Try to catch.  I'm dealing with trying to maintain an old legacy system right now that does this sort of thing and every day I curse the original developer's name.

Comment: Try using a SQLException instead of an Exception as your exc object, and then do a Select Case on exc.Number.  I believe 2627 is for a unique key constraint, which is what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a refactor of your code with some helpful guidance.  I *think* this will compile, but if it does not, then you can do a little homework to figure out what is missing.

```vb
Try
    ' the USING block guarantees that the object's Close() and Dispose() methods are fired automatically when you exit the block
    Using sqlconn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Database=QuizDB; Integrated Security = true")
        Using sqlcmd As SqlCommand = sqlconn.CreateCommand
            With sqlcmd
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text

                ' parameterized query to protect against SQL injection
                .CommandText = "INSERT INTO reg_info(uname,pass,fname,lname,dob,course,college) VALUES (@username, @password, @firstname, @lastname, @dob, @course, @college)"
                With .Parameters
                    .Clear()
                    .AddWithValue("@username", user_name.Text)
                    .AddWithValue("@password", con_pass.Text)
                    .AddWithValue("@firstname", first_name.Text)
                    .AddWithValue("@lastname", last_name.Text)
                    .AddWithValue("@dob", dob.Text)
                    .AddWithValue("@course", course.Text)
                    .AddWithValue("@college", college.Text)
                End With
                .ExecuteScalar()  ' Actually executes the SQL command
            End With
        End Using
    End Using
    MsgBox("Registration successful")


Catch ex As Exception
    ' Any error in the TRY block will automatically jump to herem and the "ex" object will be an Exception object with populated properties
    MsgBox("User name already exists.  Error from database is " & ex.Message)

End Try
```